# Jacoco agent does not measure any code coverage run by exec-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I want measure code coverage with exec-maven-plugin and jacoco together.

For now, I can execute my Main class (without cover) and I can measure my coverage of my unit tests. I want to measure code coverage when running my main class.

**Run my Main class is OK (clean compile exec:java):**

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>scenarioInitiator</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.Main</mainClass>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>123456</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

**My jacoco configuration for unit test is OK (clean test):**

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
                <configuration>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                            <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>                         <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: but when running your main class you would actually not run tests, hence no test coverage can be collected. What are you trying to achieve actually?

Comment: @A. Di Matteo, I want to measure the code covered by the execution of my main class

Comment: sorry, still not clear. You want your class to measure the code covered? I mean, the expected behavior of your class should be to run all tests and measure test coverage?